# Failing HDFS checkpointing in Spark Streaming

Tags: hdfs, spark-streaming, checkpointing

after deploying my Spark Streaming Job on a Standalone Spark cluster, i got some problems with checkpointing. The console log yields a hint:

```
WARN ReliableCheckpointRDD: Error writing partitioner org.apache.spark.HashPartitioner@2 to hdfs://10.254.25.21:8020/path/1914a5db-96be-4634-b2ce-ee867119fd95/rdd-18129
```

I am using the default HashPartitioner dividing the data in two partitions. I set my HDFS checkpointing directory to my Spark master and HDFS port as follows:

```
ssc.checkpoint("hdfs://10.254.25.21:8020/path")
```

In my Job I never manually call `.checkpoint(duration)` on any DStream myself. But I got many stateful Streams resulting from [PairDStreams mapWithState()](https://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/api/scala/index.html#org.apache.spark.streaming.dstream.PairDStreamFunctions) invokations. The code of catching the exception can be found in [ReliableCheckpointRDD line 209ff](https://github.com/eBay/Spark/blob/master/core/src/main/scala/org/apache/spark/rdd/ReliableCheckpointRDD.scala). Unfortunately, I could not find any references to this error on the web.

In my job, the exception is thrown for every stateful DStream whenever checkpointing is triggered.

Any help is appreciated!

**Edit #1**

This does not affect the correctness of the results. Yet I wonder if the performance is getting worse as I am doing some performance analysis.